# Insert Object data To Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have this JSON Object Array Type Data that I want to insert into array with keys. If I do print_r, the data seen as follows :

```
[{"comment":"hola hi ","datecreated":"2017-02-27 13:53:25"},{"comment":"hola hi harambeh ","datecreated" :"2017-02-27 13:53:30"}]
```

Here's my related code :

```
$data = json_decode($_REQUEST['array']);

$formdata = [];

foreach($data as $value){
    $formdata = array('comment' => $value->comment, 'date_created' => $value->datecreated);
}
```

However, the result array only took the last object, which are

```
Array
(
    [comment] => hola hi harambeh 
    [date_created] => 2017-02-27 13:53:30
)
```

Obviously I need every data, not just last one. This should be easy in JavaScript.

Any ideas and helps much appreciated.

Comment: use `$formdata[]` in foreach loop & there is no need to insert in new array because if you use `json_decode($_REQUEST['array'],true)` gives array read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: You should read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) about `json_decode()`. Simply pass `true` as a second argument and it will be decoded as arrays instead of objects. No need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the whole array and what you need is to add an item to the array so you will need `[]`. Change

```
     $formdata = array('..........
```

to

```
     $formdata[] = array('......
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

You need change **$formdata** To **$formdata[ ]**

**Replace**

```
foreach($data as $value){
        $formdata = array('comment' => $value->comment, 'date_created' => $value->datecreated);
    }
```

**With**

```
foreach($data as $value){
        $formdata[] = array('comment' => $value->comment, 'date_created' => $value->datecreated);
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean the other way around. And why not just pass `true` as the second argument to `json_decode()` instead?

Comment: If he require some specific keys of array then above solution is better....

Comment: He was change key datecreated To date_created.

Comment: Fair enough, but your "Rreplace ... with..." is still the wrong way around. :)

Comment: Sorry bro... Please edit answer if possible..Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
foreach($data as $value){
$formdata = array('comment' => $value->comment, 'date_created' => $value->datecreated);}
```

to this

```
foreach($data as $value){
$formdata[] = array('comment' => $value->comment, 'date_created' => $value->datecreated);}
```

Problem was on assigning a new array in every iteration to same variable rather than adding a new item to existing array